# Repair broken or fallen out bolt on oven door

Tags: oven, hinges

My son has been backing chicken with some friends, and now the door of the oven is no longer horizontal, when open, but hanging to the ground. Here is an image:

[image: image of oven with door hanging open]

I guess they have let the oven door fall and some part of the hinge is broken or a bolt has sprung out. When you look at the hinge closely, you can see an empty bolt hole in the part of the hinge that is closest to the oven:

[image: close up image of oven hinge seen from the side]

When you look inside the hinge from above, you can see two strips of metal on either side. They seem to have holes in them, too, and I suppose there was a bolt through them to hold the door horizontally above the floor:

[image: close up image of oven door hinge from above]

I have found many instructions on the internet on how to replace the part of the hinge that is in the door, but few on how to remove the part of the hinge that is in the oven, and none for this model. Also, I don't want to replace the hinge. If possible, I'd like to repair the hinge.

Any ideas? The oven is a Miele H4220E.

Comment: Looks like the bolt is "Low head screw M5X4,8" part #21 on diagram. https://www4.miele.de/msd/MSD#/device/19567/etd/223704930103/

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I get a page saying "Access denied" when I follow that link.

Comment: Often ranges I had would permit removing the door . Usually by lifting the door when slightly open. I very rarely used the feature so can't say much more. My present Frigidaire does not have the feature. So ,I think there is a good chance it will slide  back if you get the right movement.

Comment: @blacksmith37 It is easy to remove the door, and I know how to. In the second image you can see a latch in the left half of the image. You lift that. Then you can pull out the door. But the part with the bolt hole stays in place. I can unscrew this by removing the small black screw about 2 cm to the lower right of the bolt hole, but that still doesn't give me access to the part where the bolt goes, as that is inside the contraption that comes out of the body of the oven. My problem is, how do I remove that part?

Comment: The mechanism is like a puzzle , but I don't know how yours works.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry [the link above](https://www4.miele.de/msd/MSD#/device/19567/etd/223704930103/) didn't work, those Germans must be protecting their data.

Here is a screenshot of the part diagram that calls the bolt a *Low head screw M5X4,8* part #21 on diagram. Depending on what browser you are using you may be able to right click on the screenshot and "open image in new tab", then expand the image.

I'm guessing the comma is a typo, I would try getting a small assortment of inverted hex (allen) head 5mm bolts, making sure I got one 4.8cm long (about 2") and a short little 4.8mm long.

[image]

Comment: It also might be worthwhile to do an image search for low head https://duckduckgo.com/?q=low+head+bolt&t=vivaldi&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a diagram that shows how to remove the part of the hinge that is inside the body of the oven? — Btw, the decimal separator in German is a comma. Don't know why they didn't change that in the translation.